# How to use setState() from another class not widget

Tags: flutter

Hello I am trying to use MVC in my app.
I have some question when I use setState() in my controller.

I am writing an app get data by bluetooth.
I want to change my widget by using setState in my controller
like this

```
class a(){
  void x(){
      StreamSubscription _notifySubscription;
      await readCharacteristic!.setNotifyValue(true);
      _notifySubscription = readCharacteristic!.value.listen((event)){
      send event data to model
      setState();
  }
}

class myWidget extends State<myWidget>{
    TextButton(onPressed:a.x)
}
```

How to write like this way

Comment: I think you can change the state by using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.

Comment: thanks! i will try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delegate a Function and implement it in your Widget.

Example:

```
class a(){
  void x(Function widgetSetState){
      //Your code
      widgetSetState();
  }
}

class myWidget extends State<myWidget>{
    TextButton(onPressed: () {
       a.x(() {
         setState(); //your setState
       });
    })
}
```